# Can I modify behavior of node's default module?

Tags: node.js, performance

I've figured out that performance degradation of node's Buffer module from [HERE](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7997).

*Is it possible replacing Buffer module so every other default modules uses the new one?*

Comment: ...replace it with what?  And is `Buffer` actually the cause?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify and override functionality in the Buffer class, however **this is not recommended**. Making functional changes to a core class will have unpredictable results, you run a high risk of breaking other code that uses this class.

It's better to expose your replacement as it's own module and ensure your dependent code uses that directly.